# How to make Ember data stop changing my endpoints to singular and plural according to its rules?

Tags: javascript, rest, web, ember.js, ember-data

I need Ember to stop trying to guess things when making calls to the REST endpoints, but can't find a way do do so.

If I have an endpoint say, `/services`, I want ember to always call `/services` regardless if I'm making a call to `find('services')` or `find('services', 1)`

Same for singulars.

Is it possible to disable this behavior? Even if I have to override methods in the REStAdapter that'd be OK.

Thanks!

Comment: that little smartiepants hamster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, but you still should use find('service').

### Plural (this is the default implementation)

```
App.ServiceAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  },
});
```

### Singular

```
App.ServiceAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return camelized; //Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  },
});
```

### Base Singular Class

```
App.BaseSingularAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return camelized; //Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  },
});
```

Both Foo and Bar would be singular using the code below

```
App.FooAdapter = App.BaseSingularAdapter;

App.BarAdapter = App.BaseSingularAdapter;
```

Comment: This for sure resolves the issue for when I have an endpoint which is singular, but would also affect endpoints which are plural. In the case, I need Ember to stop being a smarty pants and just use whatever I provide. If I query for `services`, then hit `/services`, if I query for `card`, then hit `/card` and not `/cards`. If I use the solution above, the end points which are plural would also be queried as singular and it would break.

Comment: You aren't providing a url when you say `store.find('foo')`, it uses `foo` for finding the record type, and adapter to use.  The above example would only apply when you try and query `service`.  You could extract the functionality into a base rest adapter and reuse it for the types (example provided).

Comment: That's cool, I won't have many endpoints with singular so using a special adapter just for those seems to be the way to go. Thanks!