# Looking up a singleton with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a conventional way to look up a singleton in Ember Data? I've set up my adapter for my `GameState` model from these instructions (under "Singular"): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23974804/173630

Now, when I fetch the GameState I'd like to be able to do this:

```
store.find('gameState');
```

But that initiates a `findAll` request type in Ember Data, which expects an array, not an object.

Another option I have is to do something like this:

```
store.find('gameState', 'mine');
```

The `mine` param is ignored, but this will successfully fetch and load my GameState. The downside here is that Ember Data creates an extra `GameState` instance in my store with an id of `mine`. Is there any way to prevent this?

I'm using Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.11.

Here's what my model looks like:

```
var GameState = DS.Model.extend({
    currentPuzzle: DS.belongsTo('puzzle'),
    currentRound: DS.belongsTo('puzzleRound'),
    currentInventory: DS.attr('number'),
    moves: DS.hasMany('move', {async: true}),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the gameState? Does it have any relationships with the model where it's being called?

Comment: The GameState url is at `/api/game_state`. I updated my question to include the GameState model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately that's a side affect of doing it like this.  You can do a few different things here:

1. Hack it out using private methods/members
2. Switch to a findAll/findQuery approach changing your api and then only returning the first item from the results (which would be the only result).
3. Make a boring ajax call, and sideload the record.

#### findAll/findQuery - pain cause you have to change your api

```
return this.store.find('foo').then(function(records){
  return records.get('firstObject');
});
```

#### jquery ajax sideload

```
var store = this.store;
return $.ajax('foo').then(function(data){
  return store.push('foo', data);   // push returns the record
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

Comment: thanks for this answer. Any chance you can link me to a github issue, blog post, or anything really that explains their reasoning behind this? It seems crazy to me that ember data could exist this long without support for this

Comment: reasoning behind what, and support for what?  :)  There are two issues at play here, which one are you talking about?

Comment: without support for requesting a singleton resource. sorry that wasn't clear. what you've done here just seems like there should be something in core ember data for